# Can't install dotnet

Tags: wine, microsoft, dotnet

Every time I do

```
winetricks dotnet20
```

The install window comes up, I hit next, and then it crashes.

Here's what the terminal says

```
l@l-Aspire-5515:~$ winetricks dotnet20
Executing w_do_call dotnet20
Executing load_dotnet20
Executing w_do_call remove_mono
Executing load_remove_mono
------------------------------------------------------
Mono does not appear to be installed.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call fontfix
Executing load_fontfix
Setting Windows version to win2k
Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit C:\windows\Temp\_dotnet20\set-winver.reg
Current wine does not have wine bug 10467, so not applying workaround
Current wine does not have wine bug 30845, so not applying workaround
Current wine does not have wine bug 30845, so not applying workaround
Executing wine dotnetfx.exe
fixme:advapi:DecryptFileA "C:\\users\\l\\Temp\\IXP000.TMP\\" 00000000
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33f31c,0x00000001,0x33f344) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:seh:raise_exception Unhandled exception code c0000005 flags 0 addr 0x451d7c
------------------------------------------------------
Note: command 'wine dotnetfx.exe' returned status 5.  Aborting.
------------------------------------------------------
l@l-Aspire-5515:
```

What should I do?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this? Personally I've had trouble using wine on 12.10, 12.04 is probably more reliable.

Answer (score 3):

Did you Install *two versions* of wine/wine-mono?

I've had the same problem, did the following steps:

1. Uninstall all previous packages starting with wine using

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove 'wine*'
   ```
2. Add apt-repository using

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
   ```
3. Install Wine 1.7 from repository:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine1.7
   ```

   Now run the command:

   ```
   winetricks dotnet20
   ```

To download required file and install it correctly.

Comment: why to remove all packages?  if it exist and up to date then apt-get would simply ignore it!

Comment: @Yousef's you're right, specially when there are other packages installed and depends on those wine packages, and they would be unfortunately removed. BUT according to the question, this situation happened when you dont remove previous wine packages. maybe the best solution is to sit and wait for an stable version. if you can't wait, then it would be easier to remove all wine and depended packages, and re-install depended packages after updating your wine version (if there is any)

Comment: @MostafaNazari - I remember being able to run `winetricks dotnet20` after setting a `WINEARCH=win32` in older versions of Ubuntu after installing `ia32-libs`. currently, I am on 15.04 64b, and am facing the same problem as the question above. Can it be fixed with a stable wine installation (wine 1.6xx) ?

Comment: @3l4ng I did not face this problem recently. I think it's still the only solution: upgrade to wine 1.7

Comment: @MostafaNazari - is that stable enough?

Answer (score 0):

After installed wine 1.7 write:

```
export WINEARCH=win32
export WINEPREFIX=~/.problematic
winecfg
```

say @yes@ two times. After all work.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm ~/.wine -rf && apt-get install mono-complete wine:i386 -y && winetricks dotnet20
```

You will see. That works on ubuntu 14.04 amd64.

F.Y.I. I have installed only

> wine:i386

You may do this before installing wine:i386

```
 yes |  apt-get remove wine
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `ntlm_auth` via:

```
sudo apt-get install winbind
```

as .NET does require a working ntlm_auth.

Related:

- [All .NET versions fail to install in 1.7.18](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=22475)