# Install dotnet 2.0 on Ubuntu 15.04 without using Wine1.7

Tags: wine, 15.04, mono, winetricks, dotnet

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit, and have the following wine packages installed -

```
$ apt --installed list|grep wine
wine/vivid,now 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu8 amd64 [installed]
wine-gecko2.21/vivid,now 2.21-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
wine-mono0.0.8/vivid,now 0.0.8-0ubuntu1 all [installed]
wine1.6/vivid,now 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
wine1.6-amd64/vivid,now 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
wine1.6-i386/vivid,now 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu8 i386 [installed,automatic]
winetricks/vivid,now 0.0+20140302-0ubuntu2 all [installed]
```

I want to install **.NET 2.0** (`dotnet20`).

1. Since I'm on a 64bit machine, I set wineprefix and environment like so

   ```
   $ export WINEPREFIX="/home/usr/.wineprefixes/office2010/"
   $ export WINEARCH="win32"
   ```
2. However, installing dotnet20 gives me the following error

   ```
   $ winetricks dotnet20
   Executing w_do_call dotnet20
   Executing load_dotnet20
   Executing w_do_call remove_mono
   Executing load_remove_mono
   ------------------------------------------------------
   Mono does not appear to be installed.
   ------------------------------------------------------
   Executing w_do_call fontfix
   Executing load_fontfix
   Setting Windows version to win2k
   Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit C:\windows\Temp\_dotnet20\set-winver.reg
   Current wine does not have wine bug 30845, so not applying workaround
   Executing wine dotnetfx.exe
   fixme:advapi:DecryptFileA ("C:\\users\\usr\\Temp\\IXP000.TMP\\", 00000000): stub
   err:secur32:SECUR32_initSchannelSP TLS library not found, SSL connections will fail
   err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
   fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33f2e4,0x00000001,0x33f2d0) stub
   fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
   err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
   err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
   ------------------------------------------------------
   Note: command 'wine dotnetfx.exe' returned status 84.  Aborting.
   ------------------------------------------------------
   ```

   The installer on wine quotes on a message box `Installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify this is a valid Windows installer package`
3. I have tried opening the winetricks GUI and installing from there (the changed **WINEPREFIX** has been recognized). I have also tried `env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/usr/.wineprefixes/office2010/ winetricks dotnet20`, but I get the same error.
4. I have also tried uninstalling `wine-mono`, and then installing dotnet20, but no avail. So, I reinstalled the mono package.

A [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262960/cant-install-dotnet) says installing Wine1.7 from the PPA is one way to make things work. However, since that is not a stable version I do not wish to install it.
Can I make **dotnet20** work with **Wine1.6xx** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't install dotnet](http://askubuntu.com/questions/262960/cant-install-dotnet)

Answer (score 3):

To solve this error:

> err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated.

you need to install `winbind`:

```
sudo apt-get install winbind
```

> This Samba package provides a daemon which integrates authentication and directory service (user/group lookup) mechanisms from a Windows domain on a Linux system.

This will probably fix your main error:

> Note: command 'wine dotnetfx.exe' returned status 84.  Aborting.

as .NET does require a working ntlm_auth.

Related:

- [All .NET versions fail to install in 1.7.18](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=22475)